# SearchView on AppCompat v21 is unresponsive to touch

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview, android-appcompat

In my `ActionBarActivity` I have this code:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.near_location_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_user_search);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        setupNewSearchView(searchItem, searchManager);
        return true;
    }

    private void setupNewSearchView(final MenuItem searchItem, SearchManager searchManager) {

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)  MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        } else {
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        }

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
                if (searchItem != null) {
                    searchItem.collapseActionView();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

Now the `SearchView` should only show when I go to a specific `Fragment`, in that `Fragment`, I do this:

```
   @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

          menu.findItem(R.id.action_user_search).setVisible(true);
          menu.findItem(R.id.action_view_spots).setVisible(false);
          menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(false);
          getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

    }
```

**The Problem:**

When I go to this `Fragment`, the `SearchView`, does show, but nothing happens to the touch. It will not open or respond.  What am I doing wrong?

**Supplemental info:**

*in `ActionBarActivity`:*

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

*in `Fragment`:*

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you set `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` on your `onCreateView`?